# add record level custom latency metric in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, jmx

I trying to add a specific metric to my kafka-streams application that will measure latency and report in to the jmx.
I'm using `StreamsDSL` in scala so using the `ProcessorAPI` for metrics (which I know is possible) will not work for me.

the basic things I would like to understand is:

1. how to extract specific record properties (i.e headers) to use as part of the metric calculation
2. How to add the new metric to the metrics reported to the jmx

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to fall back to the Processor API to access record metadata like headers and to register custom metrics.

Note thought, that you can mix-and-match the DSL and the Processor API, so it's not necessary to move off the DSL. Instead, you can pluging custom `Processors` or `Transformers` via `KStream.process()` or `KStream.transform()` (note, that there are multiple "siblings" to `transform()` that you might want to use instead of the `transform()`).